# TSQL Distinct Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID SuppressionTypeID PersonID
------------------------------
1  1                 123
2  1                 456
3  2                 456
```

I want to get a rolling count (distinct people) rather than a normal group by count.

e.g. not this:

```
SuppressionTypeID    Count
---------------------------
1                    2
2                    1
```

This:

```
SuppressionTypeID    RecordsLost
----------------------------------
1                    2
2                    0
```

The latter being zero as we lost person 456 on suppresiontypeid 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please can you add some more example data. Your current example is a little confusing

Comment: The result ID2 = 1, ID1=1 would also be correct. ID2 has just one record and ID1 just one other. So your results depend on their order. Is this really what you want? How do you want your results ordered then? Just randomly ordered? Or ordered by SuppressionTypeID? Or ordered such as to get the highest count first and the lowest count last? Or how else?

Comment: Ordered by SuppressionTypeID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use a temporary table or a table variable as shown below

```
     DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,SuppressionTypeID INT
    ,PersonID INT
    )

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 1
    ,1
    ,123

UNION ALL

SELECT 2
    ,1
    ,456

UNION ALL

SELECT 3
    ,2
    ,456

DECLARE @t1 TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,SuppressionTypeID INT
    ,PersonID INT
    ,firstid INT
    )

INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT *
    ,NULL
FROM @t

UPDATE t1
SET t1.firstid = t2.firstid
FROM @t1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT personid
        ,min(SuppressionTypeID) AS firstid
    FROM @t1
    GROUP BY personid
    ) AS t2 ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID

SELECT coalesce(t2.firstid, t1.SuppressionTypeID) AS SuppressionTypeID
    ,count(DISTINCT t2.personid) AS count
FROM @t1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN @t1 AS t2 ON t1.personid = t2.personid
    AND t1.SuppressionTypeID = t2.firstid
GROUP BY coalesce(t2.firstid, t1.SuppressionTypeID)
```

The result is

```
SuppressionTypeID count
----------------- -----------
1                 2
2                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
with tmp_tbl as (
  select 
    x.SuppressionTypeID, count(x.PersonID) as RecordsLost
  from (
    select 
      min(SuppressionTypeID) as SuppressionTypeID,
      PersonID
    from tbl
    group by PersonID
  ) as x
  group by x.PersonID
  order by x.SuppressionTypeID
)
select 
  distict t.SuppressionTypeID, coalesce(tmp.RecordsLost, 0) as RecordsLost
from tbl t
left join tmp_tbl tmp on tmp.SuppressionTypeID = t.SuppressionTypeID
```

Comment: But this will not return the  0 column for supressiontypeid 2, because its already elimnated in subselect. also you must group by supressiontypeid in outer select