# TSQL Distinct Counts 2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I asked the question posted here a few weeks ago and now the goalposts have moved slightly:

[TSQL Distinct Counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874550/tsql-distinct-counts)

What I have found is that SuppressionType have a priority and the count should take place by descending priority.  The problem arises is that some supressions have equal priority and in this instance, the SuppressionTypeID should be used in desceding order to make a distinct order.

To compund the issue, I am count distinct rows across multiple files, hence the fileid.

My Ideal result for the sql below would be:

```
SuppressionTypeID   FileID  PersonCount
1           8786    2
2           8976    1
2           8977    1
```

The demo code I am using (from the previous question):

```
create table #t (
    ID INT
    ,SuppressionTypeID INT
    ,priority int
    ,PersonID INT
    ,fileid int
    )

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT 1
    ,1
    ,1
    ,123
    ,8976

UNION ALL

SELECT 2
    ,1
    ,1
    ,456
    ,8786

UNION ALL

SELECT 3
    ,2
    ,1
    ,456
    ,8976
UNION ALL

SELECT 4
    ,2
    ,1
    ,789
    ,8976
UNION ALL

SELECT 5
    ,2
    ,1
    ,123
    ,8977

create table #t1 (
    ID INT
    ,SuppressionTypeID INT
    ,Priority int
    ,PersonID INT
    ,FileID int
    ,firstid INT
    )

INSERT INTO #t1
SELECT *
    ,NULL
FROM #t

UPDATE t1
SET     t1.firstid = t2.firstid
FROM    #t1 AS t1
JOIN    (
        SELECT  personid
        ,       min(SuppressionTypeID) AS firstid
        ,       FileID
        FROM    #t1
        GROUP BY FileID, PersonID, Priority
        ) AS t2 ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID
                AND t2.fileid = t1.FileID

SELECT  coalesce(t2.firstid, t1.SuppressionTypeID) AS SuppressionTypeID
,       t1.FileID
,       count(DISTINCT t2.personid) AS PersonCount
FROM    #t1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN #t1 AS t2 ON t1.personid = t2.personid
                    AND t1.SuppressionTypeID = t2.firstid
GROUP BY coalesce(t2.firstid, t1.SuppressionTypeID),  t1.FileID
Order by t1.FileID, coalesce(t2.firstid, t1.SuppressionTypeID)
```

This apporach doesn't have to be used if there is a better way as long as the result is correct.

Thanks in advance

I have also been try this.  I am trying to get a rank of 1 and from there I can tally up where the rank = 1, but this isn't quite working either:

```
;WITH CTE AS    (
            SELECT  SuppressionTypeID
            ,       FileID
            ,       PersonID
            ,       [Priority]
            ,       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID, [Priority], PersonID ORDER BY SuppressionTypeID) AS FirstID
            FROM    #t
            )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Ideally my result would be:

```
SuppressionTypeID   FileID  PersonID    Priority    FirstID
1           8786    456     1       1
1           8976    123     1       1
2           8976    456     1       2
2           8976    789     1       1
2           8977    123     1       1
2           8977    456     1       1
```

Comment: you have two sets of ideal results.  which is it?

Comment: I was looking at a plan b Hogan. But in summary, if a person is caught by a higher priority suppression, I don't want them counting again. So whichever one that can be solved, I can work with. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the sql to parts and building up :

This will get one instance per PersonID, according to the SuppressionID,FileID... by priority

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (partition by PersonID ORDER By SuppressionTypeID,...) AS RN FROM #T) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Then use that as the source for your Count query.

Comment: That still doesn't work Amir as PersonID 123 for FileID 8977 is exlcuded.  I need distinct counts per file as I orginally stated

Comment: Fixed, my dummy data was at fault as well, your query works Amir